# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

Since I updated to Visual Studio 2015 update 3 and restored my Nuget packages I'm getting an

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

error.In my project.json file I have the following Entity Framework packages defined

```
"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Is there anything that I have to change that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a `EntityFramework.Core` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package installed. I was able to recreate the project and restore all the packages without `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Answer (score 1):

try putting this

```
  {
     "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
     "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
     }
  }
```

in global.json